# Injective functions and composition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove that a function $f \in A \to B $ is injective if and only if for all $C$, for all $g,h \in C \to A$: $f \circ g = f \circ h \to g = h$.

The $\to$ direction is proved as follows:

[$\to$]

Let $f$ be injective and suppose that $f \circ g = f \circ h$. It follows that $f(g(a)) = f(h(a))$ for any $a \in A$, whence, for all $a \in A: h(a) = g(a)$, by injectivity.

I cannot however derive the $\leftarrow$, by

Suppose for all $g,h \in C \to A$: $f \circ g = f \circ h \to g = h$ and that $f(a) = f(b)$ and, for contradiction, that $a \neq b$. It is not clear to me how to get the information that $a = b$ from these assumptions.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Our implication must be true for all $g$ and $h,$ so let's assume that there is some $x \in C$ such that $g(x) = a$ and $h(x) = b.$ Now do you see the way forward?

Comment: There must be such an $x$ because it must work for all $g$ and $h.$ Simply let $C$ be nonempty and $g(c) = a, h(c) = b.$ (also actually this is better before I missed that the *functions* must be equal and not just their values. this argument fixes that)

Comment: But what about the elements in the domain of $f$ which are not in the range of $g$ or $h$? How do we know the injective property holds of them?

Comment: The major point that makes this argument work is that our property must hold for *all* $g$ and $h,$ not just a specific choice of $g$ and $h.$ For any elements in $A$ you can choose, I can construct similar functions which take only those values and apply the same argument.

Comment: But given a specific choice of $g$ and $h$, there might be objects in $dom(f)$ which are not in the range of $g$ or $h$. I get that you can think of a different function which simply includes these, but that seems to be changing the subject: which is how, given the chosen $g$ and $h$, $f$ will be injective.

Comment: I think it would be clearer if I wrote out the entire argument in an answer, give me a sec

Comment: You are misinterpreting the assertion. It doesn't say "given the chosen $g$ and $h$, $f$ will be injective." It says "if for **any** choice of $g$ and $h$ you can make this conclusion, *then* $f$ is injective." The conclusion does not follow from a particular choice of $g$ and $h$, it follows from being able to do it for *every possible choice* of $g$ and $h$.

Comment: Ah quantifier scope

Comment: And that scope is clued in by the fact that the "for all" appears after the "if and only if". If the statement was supposed to be "for all $g,h\colon C\to A$, ($f$ is injective if and only if $fg = fh\to g=h$)", then the "for all" would have appeared first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the condition says that if something happens for *all* choice of functions, then $f$ in one-to-one, the usual strategy is to find a clever/suitable choice of functions that will imply what you want. That is the situation here.

For the converse, suppose there exist $a,b\in A$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$. We want to show that $a=b$.

Let $C=\{x\}$ be a one element set. Define $g\colon C\to A$ by $g(x)=a$, and $h\colon C\to B$ by $h(x)=b$.

Note that $f\circ g = f\circ h$, since $f(a)=f(b)$. Now, our assumption is that this implies that $g=h$. So we conclude that $g=h$. Therefore, $a=g(x)=h(x)=b$, which proves that $a=b$, as desired.

---

I like that proof, but you can also proceed by contrapositive: prove that if $f$ is not injective, then there exist a choice of $C$ and $g,h\colon C\to A$ such that $f\circ g = f\circ h$, yet $g\neq h$.

If there exist $a,b\in A$ such that $a\neq b$ but $f(a)=f(b)$, then pick your favorite nonempty set $C$, and define $g\colon C\to A$ to be $g(c)=a$ for all $c$; and $h\colon C\to A$ to be $h(c)=b$ for all $c$. Then $f\circ g=f\circ h$, since $f(a)=f(b)$, but $g\neq h$ since $g(c)=a\neq b = h(c)$ for any $c\in C$ (which is nonempty).

Answer (score 3):

Given that for all $C$ and $g,h : C \to A,$ we have $f \circ g = f \circ h \to g = h,$ we want to prove that for all $a, b \in A,$ $f(a) = f(b) \to a = b.$

Suppose we selected some arbitrary $a$ and $b$ from $A.$ Now, define functions $s: C\to A, s(c) = a$ and $t: C \to A, t(c) = b.$

Our premise that $f \circ g = f\circ h \to g = h$ applies to all functions $C \to A,$ so it must work for $s$ and $t.$ Therefore, $f \circ s = f \circ t \to s = t.$ Plugging in our values gives $f(a) = f(b) \to a = b,$ which was our objective.

Now, because this argument assumed nothing about $a$ and $b$ except that they were arbitrary elements of $A,$ this argument holds for all elements of $A.$ So, for all $a,b \in A,$ we've proven that $f(a) = f(b) \to a = b.$